# Media files showing 404 debug is false using Django development server

Tags: django, wsgi, production

I have been trying to test my Django project before deploying it on a cpanel

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
```

Comment: does media files works when Debug=True?

Comment: Yes it works fine when debug=True

Answer (score 0):

======  in project urls.py ========

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include("myapp.urls")),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

`urlpatterns` modification to serve static files is recommended in development.

If you want to serve your static files from the same server that’s already serving your site, the process may look something like:

1. Push your code up to the deployment server.
2. On the server, run collectstatic to copy all the static files into
   `STATIC_ROOT`.
3. Configure your web server to serve the files in `STATIC_ROOT` under
   the URL `STATIC_URL`. For example, here’s how to do this with Apache
   and `mod_wsgi`.

[How to use Django with Apache and mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#serving-files)

Comment: For static files i had solved it with whitenoise but the issue was with media files

Comment: it should be served with apache and mod_wsgi as mentioned in the answer. Django is not made to serve media files in the production environment. You must configure the STATIC_ROOT settings and alias webserver to directly serve.

Answer (score 0):

When we using debug=False the Django don't handle the media files so in server side we have to handle like the static files

If you are using Nginx, let it to serve media files

For Example

go to nginx/sites-available & add this

```
location /media/ { root */home/myprojectdir/myproject*; }
```